# Keeping header rows from txt file, while altering rest of data

Tags: python, python-2.7, nameerror

I have a number of txt files that represent spatial data in a grid form, essentially arrays of the same dimensions in which each value signifies a trait about the corresponding parcel of land. I have been trying to script a sequence that imports each file, adds "-9999" on the border of the entire grid, and saves out to an otherwise identical txt file.

The first 6 rows of each txt file are header rows, and shouldn't be changed.

My progress is as follows:

```
for datfile in spatialfiles:

    results = []
    borderrow = []

    with open('{}.txt'.format(datfile)) as inputfile:
        #header = inputfile.readlines()
        for line in inputfile:
            row = ['-9999'] + line.strip().split(' ') + ['-9999']
            results.append(row)
            for cell in range(len(row)):
                borderrow.append('-9999')
    results = [borderrow] + results[6:] + [borderrow]

    with file("{}-new.txt".format(datfile), 'w') as outputFile:
        for row in header[:6]:
            outputFile.write(row)
        for row in results:
            outputFile.write(row)
```

"header = inputfile.readlines()" has been commented out because it seems to cause a  NameError in which "row" is no longer recognized. At the same time, I haven't found another way to retain the 6 header rows for exporting later.

Why does readlines() seem to alter the ability to iterate through the lines of the inputfile when it is only being used to write to a variable? What am I missing? (Any other pointers on my undoubtedly bloated code always welcome!)

Comment: Please fix your indentation.  The editor has a preview function, use it before posting.

Comment: I'm aware of the previewer, I just don't look at code enough to have seen my error. Fixed.

Comment: Please could you include a sample input file showing say the first 10 lines of your txt file, and also show how that data should by output.

Answer (score 0):

`readlines()` reads the whole file into memory, parses it into a list, and leaves a pointer to the end of the file. When you try to read the same file again, it will attempt to resume reading from the pointer, which is already at the end of the file. Call `readlines()` once and loop through the list with a counter which changes the loop's behavior after 6 lines.